# How to get the environment variable set by a bash script from inside a python script?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I do have a `setenv.sh` script which is called at the begining of several others scripts, most of them being bash scripts. Obviously this script does set some enviroment variables, which are user later by these scripts.

Now, the problem is that I want to implement the same behaviour into some python scripts and I discovered that the enviroment of the python script is not updated if you run the setenv.

As I do not want to create another script which calls first the `setenv.sh` and other this myscript.py --- I am looking for a way to convince python to load these variables (parsing the seteve.h is not an option... as it is more complex).

Comment: You'll need to give some more details, or even better show the shell script. How are you setting the variables? How are you running `setenv.sh`? How are you then running the other scripts?

Comment: I used `os.system()` to call setenv but based on what I read, it doesn't matter as other methods will also start a new process which will have a copy of the parent process (py) env. This means that when the child ends, I will lose the env changes. When I do this from bash scripts it will work (as long they use export = AAA=AAAVALUE).

Comment: You cannot affect the environment of a Python process by executing an external script. That script can only affect its own environment, not the environment of the Python process that spawns it.

Comment: @chepner ... my question was about getting these variables out of it...I their values. One ugly way is to execute "setenv.sh & echo VAR1" and to parse the output... quite ugly especially if you have about 10-15 vars to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is clearly the one you don't want, which is to create a new script file for each python script.

You could, however, do roughly the equivalent by having the python script call itself. Of course, you need to signal it to not do that on the second invocation, otherwise you'll end up with an infinite (tail) recursion.

The following little "module" (which you can just import, but you should do it right at startup, before anything else) will check to see if the environment variable `SETENV` has been set, and if so, it will re-issue the python command (to the best of its ability, so it might get things wrong if it wasn't just a simple script execution) after sourcing the file named by `SETENV`. It lacks lots of error-checking and shouldn't be considered production-ready; rather a proof-of-concept:

```
# file env_set.py
import os
import sys

if sys.argv[0] and "SETENV" in os.environ:
  setenv = os.environ["SETENV"]
  del os.environ["SETENV"]
  os.execvp("bash", ["bash", "-c",
        "source " + setenv + "; exec python " + sys.argv[0] + ' "${@}"',
        "--"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

And a little test:

```
# file test_env_set.py
import env_set

import os
import sys
for name in sys.argv[1:]:
  if name in os.environ:
    print(name + "=" + os.environ[name])
  else:
    print("Undefined: " + name)

# file setenv.sh
export the_answer=42

$ python test_env_set.py SETENV the_answer
Undefined: SETENV
Undefined: the_answer
$ SETENV=setenv.sh python test_env_set.py SETENV the_answer
Undefined: SETENV
the_answer=42
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little library that does it:

https://github.com/aneilbaboo/shellvars-py

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to run `env` before export and after and than compare the results. Something like this

```
$ pwd
/tmp/test
$ cat setenv.sh
#!/bin/bash
export test=1234
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
source /tmp/test/setenv.sh
echo $test
$ ./test.sh
1234
$ python test.py
test=1234
$ cat test.py
#/usr/bin/env python
import os, subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen('env',stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
oldEnv=p.communicate()[0]
p=subprocess.Popen('source /tmp/test/setenv.sh ; env',stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
newEnv=p.communicate()[0]
for newStr in newEnv.split('\n'):
    flag = True
    for oldStr in oldEnv.split('\n'):
        if newStr == oldStr:
            #not exported by setenv.sh
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        #exported by setenv.sh
        print newStr
```

Comment: this is clearly going to work... ugly but it should work. I will test it first. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I had to accept the other answer because it's much easier, but yours is good too.

Comment: No worries, there are some decent people left on stackoverflow which are not only into reputations. We ask questions and respond answers just because we can :-)